# Am I hitting metal studs?

Tags: studs, metal

Novice here. I'm trying to install a swing arm lamp in the corner of two walls, one of which is an exterior wall. The magnetic stud finder I have indicated that there's a stud on the interior side of corner only.

The two screws (and anchors) that came with the lamp are 1.5" long and 1/4" in diameter. When I drilled into the wall, though, I made it 0.5" into the wall before the drill stopped. I can't see anything beyond the drywall.

I'm wondering if it's a protective plate (although there aren't really and outlets nearby or if I just have metal studs (it is a new apartment building). Is there anyway to tell? [image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is that really about 1/2" from a corner? If so, then you've likely hit the [corner bead](https://www.trim-tex.com/products/overview/corner-beads/).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that certainly seems plausible. Is it possible to mount the screws to the corner bead?

Comment: I'd be worried about knocking a section the corner bead off. Could you perhaps mount it further from the corner?